# utf-8 encoding of pdf content xcode

Tags: iphone, pdf

hello i am using leaves view to display pdf pages.it is working perfectly fine with pdf having english character but when call pdf which is having arabic content my app crashes.i am using the code below

```
- (id)init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {

CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("**paper.pdf**"),NULL, NULL);

        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
        mysearch= [pdfsearch alloc];
        //NSString*s=mysearch.currentData;
        //NSString*val=[mysearch loadparser];
            CFRelease(pdfURL);
    }
    return self;
}
```

can  any anyone tell me  how to encode its contents before calling its name on  cfbundlecopyresource url.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSURL to create a pdf from a proper unicode-NSString path.

Here's a snippet:

```
            NSURL *pdfUrl = [self fileUrlWithFileName:file]; 
            CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
```

(note that the __bridge is only needed if you use ARC)